# Cakephp copy whole app directory and subdirectories?

Tags: php, cakephp, directory

Hi I'm a new born programmer, trying to build a Cakephp System that allow user to register then create a directory for them and copy a prebuild system of mine to their directory for free. But I'm stack at copy my app directory to their directory. I have try to use recursive copy function but it only copy the file not all subdirectory.

Please help me with this one.

Edit:
Sorry for didn't attach the code
Here the code:

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I found the solution on this page. This recursive function can copy the whole directory to a new directory. Here's the link: http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/recursively-copying-directories-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try something like this:

<?php
foreach (
 $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
  \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item
) {
  if ($item->isDir()) {
    mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
  } else {
    copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
  }
}
?>

If you want your code snippet to be looked over please post it
```